# R efficient filtering of dataframe (varying filters defined by user)

Tags: r, filtering, performance

I wish to filter a dataframe, original.data, in R. The dataframe could have around 1-2 million observations. The dataframe has several fields and the names may vary. The user can select which fields to filter by. These field names are stored in names(all.filters), where all.filters is a list of variable length. The user may then choose the levels for each of the fields in names(all.filters). For example, this list may look something like:

```
> all.filters
$Period
[1] "2010-12-31" "2011-03-31" "2011-06-30" "2011-09-30" "2011-12-31"
[6] "2012-03-31" "2012-06-30" "2012-09-30"

$Size
[1] "L"  "VL"

$Number
[1] "11" "21" "35" "42" "45" "47" "49" "52" "57"
```

I am using the following code to apply the chosen filters:

```
attach(original.data)    
filter.names <- names(all.filters)
flag <- 1
for(filter in filter.names){
   flag <- flag*(is.element(get(filter),all.filters[[filter]]))
}
filtered.data <- original.data[flag==1,]
```

This works, but it feels a little slow. Note that get(filter) retrieves the column of original.data with column name equal to filter. I'm not sure if this is a good way to filter the data, but the variable nature of all.filters limits my choices a bit - I wanted to use subset, but I'm not sure what to put as the select argument. I would like to make this filtering step as fast as possible so that when the user updates a filter selection, the data can be plotted quickly.

Once the data is filtered, I use reshape2 to summarise the data before plotting it with ggplot2. I am thinking that it may be more efficient to apply the filters at one of these steps if possible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `data.table` with appropriately set keys. This will be memory efficient.

Then you can pass your `list` of filters to the `i` component of `[.data.table`

```
.period <- seq(from = as.Date("2010/1/1", "%Y/%m/%d"), to = as.Date("2012/1/1", 
    "%Y/%m/%d"), by = "3 months")
.size <- c("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL")
.number <- as.character(1:100)
DF <- expand.grid(Period = .period, Size = .size, Number = .number, stringsAsFactors = F)

DF$other <- rnorm(nrow(DF))

library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)

DT[, `:=`(Period, as.IDate(.period))]


##           Period Size Number    other
##    1: 2010-01-01   XS      1  0.17947
##    2: 2010-04-01   XS      1  1.43252
##    3: 2010-07-01   XS      1 -0.97142
##    4: 2010-10-01   XS      1 -0.98021
##    5: 2011-01-01   XS      1 -0.62964
##   ---                                
## 4496: 2011-01-01   XL    100  0.65831
## 4497: 2011-04-01   XL    100 -0.45277
## 4498: 2011-07-01   XL    100 -0.14236
## 4499: 2011-10-01   XL    100 -0.02376
## 4500: 2012-01-01   XL    100 -0.11525

all_filters <- list(Period = as.IDate(as.Date("2010/1/1", format = "%Y/%m/%d")), 
    Size = "L", Number = c("11", "21", "35", "42", "45", "47", "49", "52", "57"))


setkeyv(DT, names(all_filters))

DT[all_filters]

##        Period Size Number   other
## 1: 2010-01-01    L     11  1.4122
## 2: 2010-01-01    L     21 -0.4923
## 3: 2010-01-01    L     35  1.1262
## 4: 2010-01-01    L     42  1.3527
## 5: 2010-01-01    L     45 -0.3758
## 6: 2010-01-01    L     47 -0.1847
## 7: 2010-01-01    L     49 -0.8503
## 8: 2010-01-01    L     52 -1.0645
## 9: 2010-01-01    L     57 -0.6092
```

The only issue I can see is that you will have to reset the key each time to ensure you are referencing the correct columns. Also, you will need to ensure that the filter identifiers are the same class as the columns in the data.frame -- it may be easier to work with `character` not `factor` columns

### EDIT

To filter with more than level on more than one column, use `CJ`. CJ is a cross join, (the data.table equivalent of expand.grid, with keys set)

```
all_filters <- list(Period = as.IDate(as.Date("2010/1/1", format = "%Y/%m/%d")), 
  Size = c("L",'XL'), Number = c("11", "21", "35", "42", "45", "47", "49", "52", "57"))




cj_filter <- do.call(CJ, all_filters)

# note you could avoid this `do.call` line by
# cj_filter <- CJ(Period = as.IDate(as.Date("2010/1/1", format = "%Y/%m/%d")), 
  Size = c("L",'XL'), Number = c("11", "21", "35", "42", "45", "47", "49", "52", "57"))

setkeyv(DT, names(cj_filter))

DT[cj_filter]
       Period Size Number       other
 1: 2010-01-01    L     11  0.36289104
 2: 2010-01-01    L     21  1.26356767
 3: 2010-01-01    L     35 -0.18629723
 4: 2010-01-01    L     42  0.92267902
 5: 2010-01-01    L     45  1.68796072
 6: 2010-01-01    L     47  1.75107447
 7: 2010-01-01    L     49  0.24048407
 8: 2010-01-01    L     52  0.06675221
 9: 2010-01-01    L     57  0.49665392
10: 2010-01-01   XL     11  0.33682495
11: 2010-01-01   XL     21  0.67642271
12: 2010-01-01   XL     35 -0.16412768
13: 2010-01-01   XL     42  0.72863394
14: 2010-01-01   XL     45 -0.55527588
15: 2010-01-01   XL     47  1.30850591
16: 2010-01-01   XL     49  1.08688166
17: 2010-01-01   XL     52 -0.31157250
18: 2010-01-01   XL     57  0.43626422
```

You could also do

```
 setkeyv(DT, names(all_filters))

 DT[do.call(CJ,all_filters)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Initially I thought this was perfect - efficient and elegant - however, there is an issue. In the list `all_filters`, both `Period` and `Size` have a single level. This code does not work when two or more elements of `all_filters` have multiple levels (eg, if `all_filters` was the same as above, except with `Size = c("L", "XL")`). This method of filtering is super fast, so I'm going to try to work around this issue. Hopefully I can work out how to do it without a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed there would be some way of getting a cross-join instead of an equi-join (is that the right term?). This works well!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more general approach, which does not rely on hardcoding the field names: assume that your `data.frame` and your filters have the same columns/fields in the same order:

```
foo <- data.frame(Period=sample(x=c("2010-12-31","2011-01-01"),size=100,replace=TRUE),
    Size=sample(x=c("S","L","VL"),size=100,replace=TRUE),
    Number=sample(x=c("9","11","21"),size=100,replace=TRUE))

all.filters <- list(
    Period=c("2010-12-31","2011-03-31"),
    Size=c("L","VL"),
    Number=c("11","21","35"))
```

Then we need to apply `%in%` to the first column in `foo` against the first filter entry, the second column against the second entry, and so on:

```
bar <- mapply(FUN='%in%',foo,all.filters)
```

Finally, we extract those rows of `foo` where all filters match:

```
foo[apply(bar,1,all),]
```

Comment: Nice work! The only change that I would need to make would be: filtered.data <- foo[apply(bar[,filter.names],1,all),]. This is due to the fact that filters are not applied to every variable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 - the assumption you mention is not really one: just do `foo <- original.data[names(all.filters)]`. Also, for the last part, you could just do `original.data[rowSums(bar) == length(all.filters), ]`

Comment: @flodel: correct me if I'm mistaken, but `rowSums(bar)>0` would select rows where *at least one* of the filters hits - not *all* of them (equivalent to `any`), right? It's late where I am... But thanks for the upvote, anyway!

Comment: You are correct, I edited my comment. I also meant to say that `rowSums` will be a lot faster than `apply`.

Comment: @flodel: nice addition on the caveat I was worrying about, +1

Comment: Didn't realise that rowSums was faster than apply. I'll give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is data that matches ANY of the filter options? So `"L"` or `"VL"`, regardless of period, for example?

In that case, I would just do:

```
Filtered.Data <- subset(original.data, Period %in% all.filters$Period | 
            Size %in% all.filters$Size | Number %in% all.filters$Number)
```

Shouldn't take long at all. If you want data that matches all those values, replace `|` with `&` obviously. If you have a lot of filter categories, you can do a `for` loop and `rbind` that crap.

Comment: Cheers, the %in% operator is useful here. However, you may note that in my code I do not refer to Period, Size and Number directly. This is because all.filter is defined by another user. After they update the filter, the code should apply them automatically, i.e., without explicitly typing the names of the variables. I could do something like the following:                                                           paste("subset(original.data,",get(filter)," %in% all.filters[[filter]])",sep="")

Comment: However, then I would need to still do a loop to apply each of the variable number of filters, and then find the intersection of the resulting data sets.